# Display octave graph output in emacs?

Tags: emacs, plot, gnuplot, octave

When using the interactive octave prompt within emacs, plots appear in a new, separate window. (Worse, in my configuration, this window doesn't even raise itself to be seen, and can't be selected by keyboard window switching.)

Is there a way to have octave/gnuplot output show up within the emacs buffer itself?

Comment: I doubt that feature exists.  But it's an interesting question ...

Comment: It's possible to get inline images fairly easily (at least, this is implied by i.e. http://vwood.github.com/emacs-images-in-buffer.html). And gnuplot can be told to output image files rather than open windows. So the hard part seems to be done, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [Emacs IPython Notebook](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook) and [IPython octave magic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13/config/extensions/octavemagic.html) (example output: http://mentat.za.net/refer/octave_magic.pdf via https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1849/)? Disclaimer: I wrote Emacs IPython Notebook.

Comment: That's fantastic! I wish i knew about Emacs iPython Notebook sooner!